# Using and deleting all elements in a collection VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a collection that I need to loop through. I need to use each element for a task and then delete it. 
Foremost, here is my code

```
Public Sub unselectAllNodes()
  Dim tv As MSComctlLib.TreeView 'reference to treeview
  Set tv = Forms("Main").ESDTreeView.Object
  Dim i As Long
  For i = 0 To nodesSelected.Count
     tv.Nodes(nodesSelected.Item(0)).BackColor = vbWhite
     tv.Nodes(nodesSelected.Item(0)).ForeColor = vbBlack
     nodesSelected.Remove 0
  Next i
End Sub
```

When I try to run this code I get a couple of unexpected occurences.

1. I get an "Invalid procedure call or argument" error when I try to do nodesSelected.Item(0)

   - I also tried simply nodesSelected(0)... I am not sure which syntax if either is correct. Also not sure if this is an error coming from the 2nd point in my list.
2. When my collection is empty, the code enters the for loop anyways

Comment: Re 2:  `For i = 0 To 0` will execute once, with `i` equal to `0` so, yes, you would expect the code to enter the loop.  (You probably meant to say `For i = 1 to nodesSelected.Count`)

Comment: So I should initialize i to 1?

Comment: If by "initialise" you mean "set the 'start value' to 1" then yes.

Comment: I would actually use a `While nodesSelected.Count > 0` `...` `Wend` loop there.

Comment: Yes that is a more natural way to do what I am trying to do thanks. Now my error is "subscript out of range" when executing nodesSelected.Item(0)

Comment: VBA Collection object indexing is one-based, not zero-based.  When the Count property is evaluated it happens only once during the loop setup: it is not re-evaluated for each iteration.  When deleting objects from a collection it's best to move backwards

Comment: @TimWilliams I was just reading your answer to another question (where you got caught out because multi-page tabs are 0-based) and then I come back here and find you having to explain that collections are 1-based and not 0-based.  I love the consistency of VBA!

Comment: Keeps us on our toes...

Comment: Feels so unnatural. Thank you guys for your help.